# NFS - file system UUID and label changed during crash

Tags: external-hdd, nfs, drive, uuid

I was streaming a movie over NFS and it cut out about 1 hr in. The drive was in a 4 x 4 tb box. The drive with the movie (drive 2) on it now won't mount at boot. I took a look at the label and the UUID of drive 2. These were changed to match those of drive 1 after the crash. Running repair filesystem in ubuntu disks didn't fix the issue.

Response to comment 1:
short answer: lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,UUID gives
`sdb

└─sdb1  Blorp       e2ca2330-9556-4c79-abe9-4e8d6d20bc99
sdc

└─sdc1  Blorp       e2ca2330-9556-4c79-abe9-4e8d6d20bc99
sdd

└─sdd1  WeWormin    be26114f-7a34-472c-b556-4de1d94ba288
sde

└─sde1  Robodrive   a75d7acf-6b9e-4a0c-939f-0b1b5e2d7b49`

Long answer: I figured out that something was up because I tried rebooting the server and it went into emergency mode because my fstab didn't have a `nofail` option for these drives.

Note: When I plug the box into my mac, I can see the correct UUIDs and lables, but can't mount or repair on the mac.

Comment: you did `lsblk -o LABEL,UUID` and realize that these got changed, or did you `cat /etc/fstab` and realize that the values in that file have been changed? You should fix your `fstab` to correspond to the values that you get from `lsblk`.

Comment: See edited question above